# For real values with $abc\neq0$, if $\frac{xb+(1-x)c}{a}=\frac{xc+(1-x)a}{b}=\frac{xa+(1-x)b}{c}$, show that $x^3 = -1$ and $a=b=c.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Let $a,b,c$ and $x$ are real numbers such that $abc \neq 0$ and $$\frac {xb+(1-x)c} {a} = \frac {xc + (1-x)a}{b} = \frac {xa+(1-x)b}{c}.$$ Prove that $x^3=-1$ and $a=b=c.$

**My attempt** $:$ If $a+b+c \neq 0$ then $$\frac {xb+(1-x)c} {a} = \frac {xc + (1-x)a}{b} = \frac {xa+(1-x)b}{c} = \frac {\left [\{xb+(1-x)c\} + \{xc + (1-x)a\} + \{xa+(1-x)b\} \right]} {a+b+c} =1.$$ Therefore $$x = \frac {a-c}{b-c} = \frac {b-a} {c-a} = \frac {c-b} {a-b}.$$

Comparing the first two expressions of $x$ and simplifying we get \begin{align*} a^2+b^2+c^2 - ab - bc -ca & = 0 \\ \implies (a-b)^2+(b-c)^2 +(c-a)^2 & = 0. \end{align*} Therefore we have $a=b=c.$ But then $x$ would be an indeterminant form. Does it imply that $a+b+c = 0$? How to proceed further? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Why do you assert that $a+b+c\ne 0$?

Comment: $x=0$ and $a=b=c$ also satisfy your equation, I think you are missing some statement

Comment: Try multiplying the equality by $abc$, in this way you will not have to make any assumptions not given by the question and I think it will lead you to the answer much more nicely.

Comment: If $a=b=c$ the equations become $1=1=1$, so $x$ can be anything.

Comment: could you link the video?

Comment: I don't want any bullshit impatient rude people to answer my question like one of those who answered below. It's a worthless website where moderators are all in all and remaining others are useless stamp collector.

Answer (score 1):

if $a=b=c$ is not true one can multiply  three expressions of $x$ in from OP's thisrd step of $x$ to get $x^3=-1$. So $a+b+c \ne 0$ from OP's second equatiom. Hence either $x^3=-1$  or $a=b=c$.

Comment: But what will happen if $a+b+c=0$ such that $a= b =c$ doesn't hold?

Comment: Mr Dsc it may so happen that $a+b+c=0$ even if $a=b=c$ fails to hold. For instance take $a=2,b=3$ and $c=-5.$  What will happen in such cases?

Comment: @Phi beta kappa if you use these values in the original  pairwise linear equations of you will get three different values of $x$ which is in consistent. So this result holds when a+b+ c\ ne 0, then either $a=b=c or x^3=-1$.

Comment: Which values are you referring to here to be used? I have just taken a convenient case to work with which is $a+b+c \neq 0.$ If $a+b+c=0$ then you can't anymore apply the technique I used to solve it and so you can't have those nice values of $x$ in the form of fractions so that one can determine from there that $x^3=-1.$

Comment: your values 2, 3, -5. I am trying a very clear solution in a short wile from now.

Comment: Solved it with the suggestion given by Yves Daoust. His approach looks better to me than that of yours in view of clarity. You didn't show explicitly as to why $a+b+c = 0$ with $(a=b=c)^c$ yields an inconsistent system of equations.

Comment: By the OP's relations, $x=-1$ implies $a=b=c$.

Answer (score 1):

$$bc((b-c)x+c)=ca((c-a)x+a)=ab((a-b)x+b)$$

has a solution in $x$ iff

$$\begin{vmatrix}bc(b-c)&bc^2&1\\ca(c-a)&ca^2&1\\ab(a-b)&ab^2&1\end{vmatrix}=-abc(3abc-a^3-b^3-c^3)\\=-abc(a+b+c)(a+\omega b+\omega^2c)(a+\omega^2b+\omega c)=0$$
where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity.

There are two cases:

- one of the complex factors vanishes when $a=b=c$, and $x$ is indeterminate;
- $a+b+c=0$ and the equations reduce to

$$2x=1.$$

The correct answer is

$$\color{green}{a=b=c\lor \left(a+b+c=0\land x=\frac12\right)}.$$

Comment: @Phibetakappa: "if $a+b+c\ne0$ so that $a=b=c$ fails to hold": what ??

Comment: So the correct version should be to prove either $x= \frac 1 2$ or $(a=b=c).$ Am I right?

Comment: But if $\lnot (a=b=c)$ then obviously $a+b+c=0$ what I showed in my attempt. But that will imply $x = \frac 1 2.$ So either $(a=b=c)$ or $x = \frac 1 2.$  What's wrong in asserting it? Because my attempt shows that if the given identities hold then $$\left \{(a,b,c) \in \Bbb R^3\ |\ a+b+c \neq 0 \right \} \subseteq \left \{(a,b,c) \in \Bbb R^3\ |\ a=b=c \right \}.$$

Comment: I don't know whether you have observed it or not @Yves Daoust that if $x=\frac 1 2$ then indeed either $a+b+c=0$ or $a=b=c.$ There are many things to investigate unless vaguely argued something to humiliate somebody. That's why I hate the word "obvious" in Mathematics which E.T. Bell rightly pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's true. Let $x=1/2$. Then:
$$\frac {b+c} {2a} = \frac {c + a}{2b} = \frac {a+b}{2c}.$$
Any $a,b,c\ne 0$ such that $c=-a-b$ and $a+b\ne 0$ are a solution for that:
$$\frac {b-a-b} {2a} = \frac {-a-b + a}{2b} = \frac {a+b}{-2a-2b} \implies \frac {-a} {2a} = \frac {-b}{2b} = \frac {a+b}{-2(a+b)} \implies -\frac {1} {2} = -\frac {1}{2} = -\frac {1}{2}.$$

Moreover, if $a=b=c$, then any value of $x$ satisfies the identity:
$$\frac {xa+(1-x)a} {a} = \frac {xa + (1-x)a}{a} = \frac {xa+(1-x)a}{a} \implies \frac {1} {a} = \frac {1}{a} = \frac {1}{a} \implies 1=1=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

**A Comment and the full scenario:**

$a,b,c,x$ are real and $abc \ne 0$

**Case (1) : $a+b+c \ne 0$**

**(i): $a \ne b \ne c:$**
We get $x^3=-1\implies x=-1$ (from OP's work if multiply three expressions of $x$) without $x$ becoming indeterminate ($0/0$).

**(i): $a=b=c$ :** After OP's second-step we can write two equations for $a,b,c$
as $$-a+xb+(1-x)c=0~~~(1),~~~ (1-x)a-bx+xc=0$$ Solving by Cramer's method, we get
$$\frac{a}{x^2-x+1}=\frac{b}{x^2-x+1}=\frac{c}{x^2-x+1} \implies a=b=c, ~as~ x^2-x-1 \in R, \forall ~x \in R-\{0\}.$$ So when $a+b+c \ne 0$ and $a=b=c$, $x$ is an arbitrary real number.

**Case (2): $a+b+c=0:$** The value $x=1/2$ satisfies the the main equation of the question.

Finally we comment that if $a+b+c \ne 0$ and $a=b=c$, then $x=-1$ is only one out of infinitely many real numbers.

Comment: In case $(1)$ you proved that if $a+b+c \neq 0$ and $\color{blue} {a \neq b \neq c}$ then $x=-1$ and at last you wrote that "Finally we comment that if $a+b+c \neq 0$ and $\color{red} {a = b = c}$ then $x=-1$..." Aren't these two statements contradictory?